# ViewPager.OnLongClickListener doesn't fire

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onlongclicklistener

I want to create a menu when the user makes a long click at the view pager, but the listener doesn't fire.
Here's my code:

```
private void setListener() {
        this.mViewPager.setOnLongClickListener(new AlertDialogDisplayer());
    }


private class AlertDialogDisplayer implements OnLongClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

        private final String[] items = {"Start Slideshow from Beginning", "Start Slideshow from here"};

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mViewPager.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Select an action");
            builder.setItems(items, this);

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            beginSlideshow(arg1);
        }
```

beginSlideshow(arg1) should start the Slideshow from the beginning or the picture, where the user actually is.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: A `ViewPager` has nothing to long click upon. Put your `OnLongClickListener` on something inside the page.

Comment: how do i get something inside?
That's the only I have on that activity.
but how can I get something the view pager shows currently?

Comment: "how do i get something inside?" -- your pages (fragments, presumably) are responsible for detecting these long click events. The pages can then raise an event to let something know about the long click events (e.g., post a message on a greenrobot EventBus message bus, call a method on the hosting activity).

Comment: How can I get the listener on the fragment?

Comment: You put the listener on a relevant view in the fragment. You appear to be writing a slideshow, so if you are using an `ImageView` to display the slides, perhaps that is where you should put the listener.